# Receive data from Apply With LinkedIn

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc-3, linkedin-api

I am using the Data-Url option in the Apply With LinkedIn button. I have the data-url pointing to an action in my controller. I can confirm that my action is being hit after I complete an application using the Apply with LinkedIn button, however I don't know how to receive the data. My application is built in C# and MVC3.

https://developer.linkedin.com/application-response-data-structure
Here is an example of the response from LinkedIn, I am receiving it as a JSON but I have no idea how to accept a JSON like that one.

https://developer.linkedin.com/processing-results-code-samples
Here are some examples on how to parse it but they seem to parse a post body and not a JSON so i'm a bit confused.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx

Scroll down to the part titled "JavaScript and AJAX Improvements".

What we're doing is similar to if we were sending you an HTTP POST of JSON via AJAX (even if it's not coming via AJAX, but your script shouldn't care).

I'm not a C# guy, but that seems to be what you're looking for.